# How do I find mat-select using selenium webdriver

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am using selenium web driver to automate an angular website. I couldn't able to use select commands. because the error shown as 
Element should have been "select" but was "mat-select"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRW3O.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1tHO.png)

```
<div class="mat-input-infix mat-form-field-infix"> <mat-select _ngcontent-c2="" class="mat-select ng-tns-c6-1 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" role="listbox" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-model="award" ng-reflect-disabled="false" id="mat-select-0" tabindex="0" aria-required="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-owns="mat-option-1 mat-option-2" aria-multiselectable="false"><div class="mat-select-trigger" aria-hidden="true" cdk-overlay-origin=""><div class="mat-select-value"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span class="mat-select-value-text ng-tns-c6-1" ng-reflect-ng-switch="false"><!----><span class="ng-tns-c6-1">Award</span><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"
}--></span></div><div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper"><div class="mat-select-arrow"></div></div></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-_deprecated-origin": "[object Object]",
  "ng-reflect-_deprecated-positions": "[object Object],[object Object",
  "ng-reflect-_deprecated-offset-y": "-15",
  "ng-reflect-_deprecated-min-width": "206",
  "ng-reflect-_deprecated-backdrop-class": "cdk-overlay-transparent-backdr",
  "ng-reflect-_deprecated-scroll-strategy": "[object Object]",
  "ng-reflect-_deprecated-open": "false",
  "ng-reflect-_deprecated-has-backdrop": ""
}--></mat-select> <span class="mat-input-placeholder-wrapper mat-form-field-placeholder-wrapper"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></span></div>
<span class="mat-option-text">Institute Proposal</span>
```

Comment: can you try `driver.findElement(By.tagName("mat-select"));` ?

Comment: not working error shown as Element should have been "select" but was "mat-select"

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML.

Comment: //link_to = driver.findElement(By.id("mat-select-0"));
  link_to= driver.findElement(By.tagName("mat-select"));
  Select dropdown = new Select(link_to);
  dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Awards");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As its not containing the `<select>` tag, You need to manually select it.

You can select it with:

**Id:** `By.id("mat-select-0")`

OR

**Xpath:** `//mat-select[@ng-reflect-model="award"] OR //mat-select[@id="mat-select-0"]`

For your case :

driver.findElement(By.id("mat-select-0")).click();

Updated last 3 lines:

```
//add click() method
driver.findElement(By.id("mat-select-0"));
//Remove below 2 lines
Select dropdown = new Select(link_to);
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Awards")
```

Comment: I tried this. but error is till there. what about the select dp = new select command here?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "mat-select"

Comment: We require to see your trial code as Well, Please update your question with HTML code and Your trial code.

Comment: You are passing locator to <select> tag, which will not work for your case because of <mat-select>. Remove both <select> line, You just need to pass id of <mat-select> and click it. Refer my updated answer.

Comment: then how can i select the 2nd value from the mat-select?

Comment: Share that HTML which contains Drop down value, in your shared HTML I didn't found it. Else inform where is drop down selected text. You can share with screenshot.

Comment: shared images.first images shows  the dropdown and 2nd image shows the values displayed in the dropdown

Comment: @MeeraSNair dear you need to share complete HTML, otherwise How can I provide you solution. You need to share HTML, something like this http://prntscr.com/jx5lm3 The attribute of your drop down values.

Comment: @MeeraSNair Also, Please delete HTML , Exception details from Comment and Add it in your question. It is effective way to represent question.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the same issue. Try the following snippet.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("mat-select-0")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath to the awards text,'Awards')]")).click();
```

Comment: E.g. -: driver.findElement(By.id("mat-select-0")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='mat-option-text' [contains(text(),'Awards')]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem like this:

In the component's html code, i have created the id of each of the elements dynamically:

```html
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="idRoom" id="roomSelected" name="roomSelected">
  <mat-option [value]="null">-- Select a room --</mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let room of rooms; let i = index" [value]="room.id" [id]="'room' + i">
    {{room.identifier}} - {{room.type}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Then I have created the next method in my class Selenium:

```java
private WebDriver driver;

public TestUtil(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
} 

public void matSelectInput(String id, String value) {
    driver.findElement(By.id(id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(value)).click();
}
```

Finally, to make the test I add the following call:

```java
@Test
public void addOnSuccess() {
    ...
    testUtil.matSelectInput("roomSelected", "room0");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

select will only work with  tag not with mat-select. We need to do it manually. I faced the same issue and resolved by

#this is in python, change accordingly in Java

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath for clicking the drop-downmenu).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "<option xpath here>"))).click()
```

#option xpath is the path when u open the dropdown and all option are visible , click on the target value and take xpath.

Note: Don't take option xpath after selecting any option and then try to take xpath of the item.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("mat-select-0")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("mat-option-0")).click();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.